# How to handle auth-token and api-keys for dynamically created sub-accounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-conversations

In a different question, it was recommended that for ISVs, we create a new subaccount for each customer-organization. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73310624/4816322. This brought up a few more questions.

**Assumption:** I'm assuming that for [APIs where an account-SID is required](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource), we can no longer universally use the master-account-SID. We would need to use the subaccount-SID where the resource was or should be created.

**Question 1:** I'm assuming that for [APIs where an API key needs to be provided](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/create-tokens), we can no longer use the master-account's API key? This means that whenever we dynamically create a subaccount, we would also need to dynamically create a new API-key for that subaccount, and then store that api-key's secret in our data store, and then dynamically retrieve it when needed to perform certain API operations. Same goes for the account auth-token as well. Is this accurate?

**Question 2 (more important):** Looking at the Java sample for [this API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/user-resource):

```
Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
User user = User.creator("RedgrenGrumbholdt").create();
```

As discussed earlier, I'm assuming that the `accountSid` and `authToken` need to be subaccount-specific. However, we have a single fleet of servers for all customers using different subaccounts. Each server runs a multi-threaded JVM to serve the requests. Imagine if there are 2 requests in parallel. The first request is using twilio-subAccount1, and the second request is using twilio-subaccount2. This means that the `Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)` invocations will overwrite one another, since they take effect for the entire JVM. Instead of creating 1 user in subaccount1 and the 2nd user in subaccount2, we may end up with both users being created in the same subaccount.

The only way I can think to avoid this problem is to serialize every single twilio API call, even if the JVM is designed to handle a large number of concurrent requests. Or to bypass the Java-SDK entirely and construct/parse the HTTP request/response myself.

Am I missing something here, or is it practically impossible to use the Java-SDK to concurrently manage multiple twilio subaccounts without severe performance limitations?

**Edit:** After digging a bit more, I'm seeing that we can build a custom `TwilioRestClient`, and use it to make the API calls. I'm assuming this is what the modified code should look like, to handle concurrent requests on multiple subaccounts?

```
var myClient = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(subaccountSid, subaccountAuthToken).build();
User user = User.creator("RedgrenGrumbholdt").create(myClient);
```

I'll leave this question up since I'm still unsure about the above, but please let me know if I've misunderstood anything or if there are any other suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question 1

Yes, and there is an [API to create API Keys](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/keys/api-key) given the Account Sid and Auth Token of a Subaccount.

> Question 2

Yes, if you want to use different subaccounts, then the singleton version of the client won't work for you. That is the correct pattern for building a new, independent client object.

Comment: If we have multiple subaccounts then it means we need to maintain multiple conversation client correct?

Comment: @AjitKumarDubey that is correct